# UTF-8 glyphs are too small

Tags: terminal, font, text, encoding, utf-8

I have been setting up my new terminal on both of my MacBooks Pro and I noticed that UTF-8 glyphs are way smaller on one of them. This holds true in every application and I can't find the setting that differs between the two laptops so I can get the big glyphs on both. Here are two pictures showing the difference:
[image: Big glyphs(how I would like them to be)]
[image: Small glyphs]

I thought it would be related to the `locale` variables but no: `LANG="fr_FR.UTF-8"` and `LC_ALL="fr_FR.UTF-8"`.

Any help is welcome!

PS: I work on Mac OS Sierra

Comment: The encoding should be irrelevant, it's the font that matters.  Same one on both machines?

Comment: Font in the same in the example shown above but, as I said, it holds true for every application. Even in my web browser the alignment and size is not the same. (For instance http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b22/index.htm)

Comment: In Character Viewer, look in the Font Variation pane for 2b22 and see if there is a difference in size among the fonts that have it.

Comment: It does, there are 2 different sizes possible! But I don't get why it would be rendered differently across my 2 laptops...